TinyButStrong/DOCX. Как удалить часть документа DOCX после указанного тегом места
Я делаю заполнение шаблона DOCX, используя TinyButStrong. В шаблоне несколько (12) страниц с карточками по 4 на каждой. Кодом в цикле заполняются эти карточки.
При заполнении, иногда данных есть только для одной-двух страниц.
Мне необходимо пустые(оставшиеся незаполненными) листы удалить. чтобы при распечатке на принтере (автоматическая отправка) не выводились пустые листы. Как это сделать? можно ли в  TinyButStrong к примеру в конец последнего заполненного листа вставить какой то символ и после него все остальные листы удалить?
   $tbs->Plugin ( TBS_INSTALL, OPENTBS_PLUGIN );
   $tbs->ReplaceFields($zam);
   // Вот тут мне нужна команда очистки (удаления до конца документа)
   $tbs->Show ( OPENTBS_FILE, $copyFile );



Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Пожалуйста, задайте вопрос на русском, это StackOverflow на русском

Описал на руссском
